# Chacter recognition from video

Tags: python, r, video

I have a set of videos in mp4 of the change in reading on a scale as a mass is loaded and removed. Is there any way of finding the following in any sort of automated way in R or python:

1. The time it takes to reach a stable maximum value
2. The maximum value

I've found a Matlab example of text detection from natural but not seen an R version. Any thoughts are much appreciated.

images https://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/automatically-detect-and-recognize-text-in-natural-images.html?prodcode=VP&language=en

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [`tesseract`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tesseract/index.html)? (I haven't, just a thought.)

Comment: Nice scale, you'll want to look at `av` in R, provides bindings to FFmpeg which facilitates cropping to your region of interest, then on to by frame MNIST ml approach.

Comment: Thank you for both your suggestions. I have just tried tesseract with this particular picture and it picks up .0643 which is a very good start. Maybe cleaning up the picture somehow might help. @Chris They are actually videos to start with so I'd have to split by frame first, crop and re-bind?